# Resolve DependencyObject through binding from source property

Tags: wpf, binding, binding-expressions

For my example let's say I have this in my DataContext :

```
    public object SomeProperty 
    {  
        get;
        set{ .... 
               PropertyChanged(....);  
           }
    }
```

XAML :

```
   <ContentControl Tag="{Binding SomeProperty}" x:Name="myContentControl" />
```

Now in my `DataContext` I need to reference `myContentControl`.

Is there any way through the **Binding**  object created to resolve the binding **Target** (ContentControl.TagProperty) through the Binding **Source** (MyViewModel.SomeProperty)?

Question Context :

I have a CustomControl Deriving from DataGrid , this grid supports Filtering throw the header , 
inside the header template i placed a TextBox .
The grid itself listens to TextChanged event and filters each column by that text .

Instead of saving a reference to each TextBox , or alternatively traversing the VisualTree 
I was wondering if i could track the TextBox from the reference i saved to textBox.Text.

```
 var filterValue = textBox.Text;
 values.Add(source,filterValue); // Dictionary
```

tow questions come to mind :

1) Because Text is a string and there for immutable i'm not sure how binding keeps track of it .

2) Is it possible to resolve the Binding Target from the Binding Source (Path) ?

Comment: That's not how it is supposed to be used. Why do you need to access `myContentControl` in your view model?

Comment: I don't it was an arbitrary example of what i need , so i won't get asked questions that begin with "Why" , 
I failed :(

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have a Control Deriving From DataGrid , in each ColumnHeader a have a TextBox , which i wan't to resolve through the TextProperty i saved a reference to , Now this raises the question does binding update it's source for emutable objects.. ( So i didn't want to get into that yet ).

Comment: If that's not what you want to actually do, maybe update your question to show what you really want to do. There is no point in answering this question if that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I disagree , I'm asking a clearly Theoretical question , in order to grasp a bigger picture of what can and can't be done , my implementation and objectives should be of no interest to the good people here .

Comment: Very often, people ask one question when they actually should ask another question (see [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)). To identify such questions and safe everybody a lot of time, the context is relevant.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i edited the question . 10x.

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel for your Grid. That will save you from having to do a lot of winforms-like horrible hacks.